# MAMTIM and MAMCR in LPC

Tags: arm

I want to know that if I want to enable the MAM Function in lpc 2468 should i specify both the MAMTIM AND MAMCR registers or only MAMCR.

```
Is it necessary to specify MAMTIM along with MAMCR for enabling the working of MAM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MAM stands for Memory Accelerator Module .It is used to increase the performance of the controller.

**MAMTIM**: It means **MAM timing register** . Its **reset value is 7**.

**MAMCR**: It means **MAM Control Register**. Its **reset value is 0**.

yes it is ***necessary to specify both MAMTIM and MAMCR***.

**The value of MAMTIM and MAMCR has been specified in the startup file of the controller  in 
which MAMCR has a value of 2 and MAMTIM has a value of 4.**